# Image slideshow not showing on load Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios, vue-component

I am using a slideshow so that the user can see any extra images that the globalgiving api may have. But, the issue is that when the page is loaded and when you open a modal the slideshow is not there, unless you select open of the tabs that I have implemented within the modal. But, these tabs have nothing to do with the slideshow.

Below is the HTML code that I am using:

```
    <div v-if="projectData.images" class="
     <div class="slider_list">
       <img v-for="(src, index) in projectData.images.slice(0, 5)" :key="src" :src="src" v-show="index === active">
     </div>

     <button class="slider_prev" @click="change(active-1)">prev</button>
     <button class="slider_next" @click="change(active+1)">next</button>

     <ul class="slider_dots">
        <li v-for="(src, index) in projectData.images.slice(0, 5)" :key="src" :class="{active:index === active}" @click="change(index)">
           <button>{{index}}</button>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div v-else class="bigImage" :style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + projectData.banner + ')'}"></div>
```

Below is the Javascript code that I am using:

```
change: function(index) {
      if (this.projectData.images.length < 5) {
        this.direction = index > this.active ? 1 : -1
        this.active = (index + this.projectData.images.length) % this.projectData.images.length
      } else if (this.projectData.images.length = 5) {
        this.direction = index > this.active ? 1 : -1
        this.active = (index + this.projectData.images.length) % this.projectData.images.length
      } else if (this.projectData.images.length > 5) {
        this.direction = index > this.active ? 1 : -1
        this.active = (index + this.projectData.images.length) % this.projectData.images.length
      }
    }
```

`projectData` is an Object prop that is coming from the parent component.

However, when I log out `this.projectData`, the full object shows, which has images in it. But, if I log out `this.projectData.images` then it comes out as `undefined` and I am not sure why this is happening.

This is the parent javascript code:

```
if (project.imageGallerySize > 1) {
        axios.get(`https://api.globalgiving.org/api/public/projectservice/projects/${project.id}/imagegallery?api_key=71774a46-da0c-4748-a5ea-7001d6a47709`, {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
          }
        }).then(response => {
          projectObject['images'] = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < response.data.images.image.length; i++) {
            projectObject['images'].push(response.data.images.image[i].imagelink.filter(function(image) {
              if (image.size == 'orginal') {
                return true;
              }
            })[0].url);
          }
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log("Wrong", error)
        })
      }
```

If someone can please help, it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you output a reactive vue object to the console, the console does not display the value of its properties right away. The console only calls the "getter" functions of the reactive objects when you click on them to display them.

In code:

```
console.log(this.projectData); // <-- the printed properties are only the getter functions, not their values
console.log(this.projectData.images); // <-- the output will be the current value of this.projectData.images
```

That would explain the seemingly contradictory results in the console.

My guess as to why this is happening is because you try to use `this.projectData` before the axios request is finished. To prove it, you can add `console.log(this.projectData.images)` to your `then()` method and see the output (or use the debugger).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but how comes the slider doesn't show until I select a tab?

Comment: No idea. Just gave this to help you debug your code